# What is the sort order of returned results for search.get_indexes() in google app engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, gae-search

I am using the search.get_indexes() function as documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/functions#get_indexes), to get the list of search indexes that I have stored. From a few test cases, it seems that the returned list is sorted alphabetically on the Index name. Is it known or documented that this behaviour is guaranteed? I might have missed something, but I couldn't find it explicitly mentioned in the docs.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It doesn't seem explicit, but the start_index_name parameter wouldn't really make sense if the results weren't ordered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the sort order is not specified in the documentation, it is not guaranteed, and the implementation may change going forward. I suggest that you sort them in your code - the performance penalty is negligible, especially if the indexes are already sorted using the same criteria that you apply.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I've planned to do.